# Entity Framework InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Okay, so here's my best shot at explaining my problem.

Using the entity framework, via an instance of my data context, i use LINQ to obtain an instance of an entity within my model called "Marketing".  This entity has relationships with other entities, as the image below shows.  Notice that the expanded relationship to a "HospitalistSurvey" has an error.  Later, i attempt to set a property's value (i.e., marketing.HospitalistSurvey.[HospitalistSurveyProperty]) and at that time i get a error saying "The null value cannot be assigned to a member with type System.Int32 which is a non-nullable value type."

[image: Debugger Code]

What should i do to begin investigating this issue?

Comment: Can you please show the code that throws you the exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you have here is the following situation:

**Entity Model**

```
public class MyEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int Value { get; set; } // note that this is non nullable
}
```

**Database Model**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyEntities](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Value] [int] NULL,
)
```

The EF will handle this setup until `MyEntities` has row where `Value IS NULL` in which case it throws the exception you are seeing because it is trying to put a null value into a non nullable type.

One solution is to change the model:

```
public class MyEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int? Value { get; set; } // this is now nullable
}
```

The other is to change the database:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyEntities](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Value] [int] NOT NULL,
)
```